# High or low game help in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a game of high or low. Roll three dice, add them up, and then guess high or low. I'm having some issues when I get to the high or low part. When I run the program it ends before I can answer high or low. Also, I'm not sure how to use a while loop to continue until the user enters a wrong guess. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    int dice1, dice2, dice3, dicetotal, i; // Variables
    char startGAMEendGame;

    // Initializing variables
    dice1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    dice2 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    dice3 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    dicetotal = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;

    // Asking the user if they would like to start the game
    printf("\nWould you like to play a game? < Y / N > ");
    scanf("%c", &startGAMEendGame);

    // First If statement to start the game
    if ( startGAMEendGame == 'Y' || startGAMEendGame == 'y')
    {
        int dice1, dice2, dice3, dicetotal, i; // Variables
        char higherOrlower;

        i = dicetotal;                          // Initializing variables
        dice1 = 1 + rand() %6;
        dice2 = 1 + rand() %6;
        dice3 = 1 + rand() %6;
        dicetotal = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;

        printf("\nAwesome. Let's get started with a simple game of higher or lower.\nYou get to guess until you are wrong. \n");

        printf("\nYour first three rolls are %d, %d, %d, and their sum is %d. \n", dice1, dice2,              
        dice3, dicetotal);

        printf("\nWhat is next your guess? Higher or Lower? < H / L > ");
        scanf("%c", &higherOrlower);

        if ( dicetotal > i && higherOrlower == 'H' )
        {
            printf("\nCongratulations! You guessed correctly. ");
        }

        if (dicetotal < i && higherOrlower == 'L')
        {
            printf("\nCongratulations! You guessed correctly. ");
        }
    }

    if (startGAMEendGame == 'N' || startGAMEendGame == 'n')
    {
        printf("\nBummer. Maybe some other time. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted the code a bit for you. I'd recommend debugging and stepping through all the lines to see which one behaves different than expected, then come back to ask for feedback once you have some more details.

Comment: I'm just starting out. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space before `%c` in the second `scanf` will solve the issue.

This happens because `scanf` does not consume the `\n` character after you enter the first character.As the Enter key(`\n`) is also a character,it gets consumed by the `scanf("%c",&higherOrlower);` and thus,your next `if` never gets executed and the program ends.The space before the %c will discard all blanks and spaces.

Comment: Another question. Since I want to game to continue after I enter high or low, I would need a while or for loop before the first if statement, right?

Comment: @RonnieMatteini ,Just the highOrlow part or the whole game?

Comment: `while` loop will suit better ,but note that the loop will never end as the user does not get another chance to end the game

Comment: My professor has yet to introduce the do while loop. Could you briefly explain how I would use it for this game?

Comment: `do{printf("play again?");scanf(" %c",&startGAMEendGame);}while(startGAMEendGame=='Y'||startGAMEendGame=='y')` at the end and the `do` at the top